# Load non precision data onto InfluxDB

Tags: time-series, influxdb, influxdb-python

Issue: I am unable to load data onto Influx DB from files that is non precise.

Error Code: ValueError: Invalid time precision is given.

But my time is batch data is generated randomly without a precision. So its not letting me load the data onto the DB. I am using python and DataFrameClient in InfluxDB clients.

client.write_points(df,"TEST",'m')

my DF structure is [Timestamp,Tag,Value]